# Prove that the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x\ln(x))^n$ is uniformly convergent in $(0,1]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I've been tasked to show the following series is uniformly convergent in $(0,1]$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x\ln(x))^n$$

I've proven that $\forall x\in(0,1] : (|x \ln(x)|<1)$, which makes the original a series a geometric series. Which means that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(x \ln(x))^n=\frac1{1 - x \ln(x)}$$

But how do I prove that the series is uniformly convergent?

Thanks!

Comment: Please use proper TeX formatting to display mathematical equations in your question from next time.

Comment: Maybe some intuition would help. What if you took a look at $\sum_{n\geq 0} x^n$ on the same interval? Is this uniformly convergent? Why (not)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you familiar with the Weierstrass $M$-test? With the observations you've provided, the uniform convergence of this series is immediate; since $x \ln{x} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and $x \ln{x} = 0$ when $x = 1$, $x\ln{x}$ is bounded over $(0, 1]$. Since you've already shown that $|x\ln{x}| < 1$ for all $x \in (0, 1]$, this implies $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (x \ln{x})^n$$ is dominated by the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n$$ for some $0 < a < 1$, and therefore converges uniformly by the Weierstrass $M$-test.

If not, that's okay; you're mostly there. As @Neckverse Herdman suggested, try comparing your situation to the convergence of a geometric series on the same interval. If you're familiar with the proofs related to series of that sort, then the transition to this one should be natural.

Comment: Thank you very much Emory, your direction helped me more than you think.
I realized that not only $|x·ln(x)|<1$, but $|x·ln(x)|\le\frac1e$, I defined the convergent series. And used Weierstrass to finish the proof.